# Double slash Apache website configuration proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm using the HTTP proxy of Apache to add SSL layer to `127.0.0.1:4444`, it works pretty well but I have a problem, there is a double slash on my web browser...

Here is the configuration

```
  #
  # Proxy
  #
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4444
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4444
  RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:4444%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
```

And I get `http://example.fr//login.view`
And I would like `http://example.fr/login.view`

Is it possible to do that and delete the slash?

Answer (score 3):

Just add final slash to the pattern, here

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4444/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4444/
```